# How to pass a variable to a Drupal callback?

Tags: php, drupal, callback, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I created a structure of field like below from within the code and not using webform UI. The reason I did this programmatically is because I have hundreds of forms and I wanted to do it once for all.

[image]

Here below is my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
            $form['submitted']['file' . $i] = array(
                '#title' => t('File'),
                '#type' => 'managed_file',
                '#description' => t('Please upload a document or image.'),
                '#default_value' => variable_get('file' . $i, ''),
                '#weight' => 100,
               );

                $form['submitted']['remove_name'] = array(
               '#type' => 'submit',
               '#value' => t('Remove'),
               //I NEED A WAY TO PASS $i AS ARGUMENT TO THE CALLBACK
               '#submit' => array('form_remove_attachment'),
               // Since we are removing a name, don't validate until later.
              '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
);
        }
```

And below the callback

```
function form_remove_attachment($i) {

    $form_state['submitted']['file' . $i]--;
   // Setting $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE causes the form to be rebuilt again.
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

Now what I need is a delete button for each attachment field to allow users to change their mind on regard the attached files. I can add it of course by JS but this way the attachments are not eliminated from $form_state.

Does anyone have some suggestions how to pass $i to the callback form_remove_attachment?

Answer (score 0):

First off, instead of `$form['submitted']['remove_name']`, you should use something similar to `$form['submitted']['remove_name' . $i]`, as you did with `$form['submitted']['file' . $i]`.

For `$form['submitted']['remove_name' . $i]` you can use a custom property, such as `$form['submitted']['remove_name' . $i]['#mymodule_file_id']`. (Replace mymodule with the short name of the module you are using.) The submission form should then use the following code.

```
function form_remove_attachment($form, &$form_state) {
  // This is the same value used for #mymodule_file_id for the clicked button.
  $file_id = $form_state['triggering_element']['#mymodule_file_id'];
  // ...
}
```

As side notes:

- The managed_file form element doesn't use the #default_value property
- Every function implemented by a module should be prefixed with the short name of the module; if the function is *private*, the first character in the function name should be an underscore, followed by the short name of the module

#### References

- The explanation given for the `$form_state` keys in [drupal_build_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7)